# Next Js gives ReferenceError: self is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, zoom-sdk

I am getting ReferenceError: self is not defined while trying to integrate zoom sdk in next js. Here is my code. This error might be coming due to server side rendering in Next Js, but i am not able to figure how to fix it. Here is the code for the same. I have picked the code from zoom's sample github repo here : https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-react-sample/blob/master/src/App-New.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ZoomMtgEmbedded from '@zoomus/websdk/embedded';

function Meeting() {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const zoomClient = ZoomMtgEmbedded.createClient();

      setClient(zoomClient);
    }
  }, []);

  function getSignature(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('/api/zoom/signature', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        meetingNumber: '123456789',
        role: 0,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        startMeeting(response.signature);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  function startMeeting(signature) {
    const sdkKey = 'YOUR_SDK_KEY';
    const meetingNumber = '123456789';
    const passWord = '';
    const role = 0;
    const userName = 'React';
    const userEmail = '';
    const registrantToken = '';
    const zakToken = '';

    let meetingSDKElement = document.getElementById('meetingSDKElement');

    client.init({
      debug: true,
      zoomAppRoot: meetingSDKElement,
      language: 'en-US',
      customize: {
        meetingInfo: [
          'topic',
          'host',
          'mn',
          'pwd',
          'telPwd',
          'invite',
          'participant',
          'dc',
          'enctype',
        ],
        toolbar: {
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Custom Button',
              className: 'CustomButton',
              onClick: () => {
                console.log('custom button');
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    client.join({
      signature: signature,
      sdkKey: sdkKey,
      meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
      password: passWord,
      userName: userName,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      tk: registrantToken,
      zak: zakToken,
    });
  }

  function createClient() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const zoomClient = ZoomMtgEmbedded.createClient();

      setClient(zoomClient);
    }
  }

  function handleJoinMeetingClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (client) {
      getSignature(e);
    } else {
      createClient();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Zoom Meeting</h1>

      <div id="meetingSDKElement">
        {/* Zoom Meeting SDK Component View Rendered Here */}
      </div>

      <button onClick={handleJoinMeetingClick}>Join Meeting</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Meeting;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem and solved. If you still have the problem, check [zoom developer community](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/zoom-sdk-self-is-not-defined-nextjs-react/91784) where I posted my solution. Hope this helps many developers.

The solution is here.

I got why this error happens. Next.js import sdk on server side where the code is executed on Node.js environment, which means there is no window object. So the error says self(window object) is not found.

The solution of this error is that you need to import sdk on client side. To import sdk on client side, we can use useEffect and dynamically import zoom sdk.

I implemented component view, but you can implement client view as well.
Here is my solution code for component view. Hope this helps everybody got this issue.

```
// app/page.jsx
"use client"
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function ZoomMeeting() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initZoomApp();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="meetingSDKElement">ZOOM HERE</div>
    </div>
  )
}

async function initZoomApp() {
  const { client, clientConf } = await initClient();
  startMeeting(client, clientConf);
}

async function initClient() {
  const ZoomMtgEmbedded = await (await import('@zoomus/websdk/embedded')).default;
  const client = ZoomMtgEmbedded.createClient();

  const clientConf = {
    authEndpoint: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    sdkKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
    signature: "",
    meetingNumber: '00000000000', // actual meeting number: user need to input
    passWord: 'xxxxxx', // actual password for the meeting: user need to input
    role: 0, // 0 implies client, 1 implies host
    userName: 'React', // username: user need to input
    userEmail: '' // user email: user need to input
  }

// fetch signature to your auth endpoint. Check the sample repo.
// https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-auth-endpoint-sample
  const { signature } = await getSignature(clientConf.meetingNumber, clientConf.role);
  clientConf.signature = signature;

  const meetingSDKElement = document.getElementById('meetingSDKElement');
  client.init({
    debug: true,
    zoomAppRoot: meetingSDKElement,
    language: 'en-US',
    customize: {
      meetingInfo: ['topic', 'host', 'mn', 'pwd', 'telPwd', 'invite', 'participant', 'dc', 'enctype'],
      toolbar: {
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Custom Button',
            className: 'CustomButton',
            onClick: () => {
              console.log('Hi, mom');
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  return { client: client, clientConf: clientConf };
}

// fetch signature to your auth endpoint. Check the sample repo.
// https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-auth-endpoint-sample 
async function getSignature(meetingNumber, role) {
  const data = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_ENDPOINT, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
      role: role
    })
  })
  const { data: signature } = await data.json();
  return signature;
}

function startMeeting(client, clientConf) {
  client.join({
    signature: clientConf.signature,
    sdkKey: clientConf.sdkKey,
    meetingNumber: clientConf.meetingNumber,
    password: clientConf.passWord,
    userName: clientConf.userName,
    userEmail: clientConf.userEmail,
  })
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to post the answer here in case the link dies in the future.

Comment: That's true. I'll do

Answer (score 0):

Zoomsdk needs to run in a browser environment but Nextjs resolves the module on the server, so the simple fix is to require/import the Zoomsdk module after the React component has been mount on the DOM by Nextjs.

```
const initZoom = async () => {
  const { ZoomMtg } = await import("@zoomus/websdk");
  ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib("https://source.zoom.us/2.16.0/lib", "/av");
  // loads WebAssembly assets
  ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
  ZoomMtg.prepareWebSDK();
  // loads language files, also passes any error messages to the ui
  ZoomMtg.i18n.load("en-US");
  ZoomMtg.i18n.reload("en-US");
};

function zoom() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initZoom();

    return () => {
      null;
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>zoom</div>;
}

export default zoom;
```